# Why Is The Parent Form Data in GravityView Repeated for each Connected Nested Form Entry

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Please can anyone please help.
I connected a GravityForm Parent Form with its Nested form in GravityView using the EntryID in the parent Form with the Parent Form ID in the nested form. In the displayed view, I noticed that the Parent Form Data is repeated for each Nested form entry. For instance, the parent form collects Club Data while the nested form collects Player Data. So for one club, i have more than one player. I expect that the Parent Form Entry should just be one for all the entries in the nested form connected to the Specific Entry ID in the ParentForm. However, in the display, the club information is repeated for each player instead of having the Club Information and then all the players beneath. Am I doing somethinh wrong?

I connected a GravityForm Parent Form with its Nested form in GravityView using the EntryID in the parent Form with the Parent Form ID in the nested form. In the displayed view, I noticed that the Parent Form Data is repeated for each Nested form entry when there should be one parent form Data for many players.